# Vertical Drawable Line on Left Border of Drawable Rectangle?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-drawable

I have been looking for similar questions and I cannot find anything that is exactly what I am looking for. I have also been messing around with this `XML` for quite some time, and I do not want to have to import any libraries or use Drawing code to make this square border.

[image: I am trying to accomplish something like this]

As you can see, there is an orange line that is behind the white border.

This is as close as I have gotten:

[image: My weird shape that is not close to right]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="90">
            <shape android:shape="line" android:thickness="3dp">
                <padding android:left="120dp"/>
                <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#F4900A"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/white"/>
        <solid android:color="#00FF0000"/>
        <corners android:radius="16dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- Background is transparent -->
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#00000000" />
        <solid android:color="#00000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I feel like I am close but I am not sure how to move this line to the left without having it scale down in size? I have been messing around with the padding and it just seems jank.

Note: I have also tried setting the white border to have a orange gradient left side, and it didn't look right - so I don't think that gradient is an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with:

- A normal rectangle as the outer white border
- An orange solid rectangle to represent the left line that has `android:gravity="left"` to position it to the left and the paddings adjusted to displace the left line to the right, top, and bottom as you need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="15dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:top="15dp">

        <rotate android:fromDegrees="180">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#FF9800" />
                <size android:width="3dp" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>

    </item>


</layer-list>
```

Previews with different `TextView` sizes:

[image]

[image]